# after installing BTNavigationDropdownMenu, unable to import

Tags: ios, swift

I just installed  [`BTNavigationDropdownMenu`](https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu/blob/master/README.md) via CocoaPods.

I tried to import it into my swift files but I am unable to.

The error is `Cannot load underlying module for 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu'`

I am not sure what other information to provide here other than I have never touch another other settings. googling around and I couldnt find anything as well.

I also went to my app's settings and there was the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` and I added `BTNavigationDropdownMenu.framework` in but nothing works.

Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you resolved this issue.

For anyone who comes across this question in future, a simple clean of the project resolved my issue.

`Product` > `Clean`

or

`SHIFT` + `COMMAND` + `K`